# C# treeview from dot notation flat file

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a flat file that looks like this:

```
.root:NODE
.root.branch1:NODE
.root.branch1.size:INT
.root.branch1.name:STRING
.root.branch2:NODE
.root.branch2.flavor:NODE
.root.branch2.flavor.cost:INT
.root.branch2.flavor.name:STRING
```

The file contents, depth, lenght, etc., will be different every time, so I can't hardcode anything (though the nodes will always be of datatype 'NODE'). I need to bring it into C# as a data source. I'm not sure what the best way to parse the file is to convert it to a structure that looks like

```
+root
 +branch1
   size:
   name:
 +branch2
  +flavor
   cost:
   name:
```

etc. Ideally, I'd like to dynamically build a treeview control that the user can use to select the node he'd like to access (these tags are paths to an actual datasource; so elsewhere in the code, I'm using)

```
int iVal = somefunction.readvar(".root.branch2.flavor.cost");
```

/edit/ if it helps, the file I'm trying  to parse is a *.SYM file (a symbols file) generated by a TwinCat 2 program. There's a little documentation here: http://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplccontrol/html/tcplcctrl_componentsoptions.htm#Symbol%20configuration

Comment: 2 questions:
- all the properties of the nodes are either string or int?
- can a node have two fields of the same type?

Comment: can you change the way your flat file is?

Comment: 1) The datatypes could be any of the simple C# datatypes ('bool, int, uint, strings', etc.), and a node can have two fields of the same type (e.g. a node could have price and weight, both as 'int's).

2) The flatfile is autogenerated by a 3rd party tool, so I don't really have any control over it's contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# :

```
private void AddToTreeView()
{
    TreeViewItem root = new TreeViewItem();
    foreach (string line in ReadLines())
    {
        var parts = line.Split(new char[] { '.' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (parts.Length == 1)
        {
            root.Header = parts[0].Split(':')[0];
            root.Tag = line;
        }
        else
        {
            TreeViewItem node = root;
            foreach (var part in parts)
            {
                var header = part.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];

                if(!IfExists(node, header, ref node))
                {
                    node.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem()
                    {
                        Header = header,
                        Tag = line
                    });
                    node = root;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    treeView.Items.Add(root);
}

private bool IfExists(TreeViewItem itm, string header, ref TreeViewItem which)
{

    if (itm.Header as string == header)
    {
        which = itm;
        return true;
    }
    foreach (TreeViewItem i in itm.Items)
    {
        if (i.Header as string == header)
        {
            which = i;
            return true;
        }
        else if (i.HasItems)
        {
            if (IfExists(i, header, ref which))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView"  Height="100">                
</TreeView>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Well, this code works but, it may have some flaws and it is not a perfect solution. Anyway, even it doesn't work perfectly, it should help you in some ways.

EDİT: 
 This way, it sometimes doesn't work, e.g. if the nodes isn't ordered.

I changed this part of the program so it should have no other errors anymore.

```
if (!IfExists(node, header, ref node))
{
    var currNode = new TreeViewItem()
    {
        Header = header,
        Tag = line
    };

    node.Items.Add(currNode);
    if (part.Contains(":"))
        node = root;
    else
        node = currNode;
}
```

The previous code's output if input is:

```
.root:NODE
.root.branch1:NODE
.root.branch2.flavor.name:STRING
.root.branch1.size:INT
.root.branch1.name:STRING
.root.branch2:NODE
.root.branch2.flavor:NODE
.root.branch2.flavor.cost:INT
```

[image]

But with the changed code, it gives output exactly as it should!

Comment: I don't have enough time now, but later I can explain the algorithm if you don't understand.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: Tag is for getting the data later by the way, just a reminder.

Comment: Woah, I didn't even catch that, very cool! It's exactly what I need to be able to actually use the control! Thanks again!

Comment: Amazing: I just ran into this issue, and here you've already fixed it! My source is pre-formatted the "right" way, but if I add a line after the file has been generated, it isn't in the right order, so this is the perfect fix! Thank you!